# Asterisk - which protocol/technology is using?

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, pbx

Asterisk installed on Linux server by other admin.

I am trying to find out which communication protocol/technology is currently using on Asterisk? Eg: isdn, voip, acd, etc. I dont know which one is using.

The line connected on BT with ISDN or T1 Card on the server.

There are a lot of files in `/etc/asterisk/`

Which config file do I need to look at and detail that connect to BT line?

Comment: If the files in /etc/asterisk/ are blurry you should fix your monitor. ;-)

Comment: Maybe, you need to start reading asterisk documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk is primarily a VoIP server using SIP, RTSP, and IAX2. it does 'speak' other protocols as well.

T1 is a type of ISDN also; though ISDN PRI lines are usually voice and T1 is data, it's the same technology.